# Regular expression to match a character that can only appear once in a string?

Tags: regex, perl, character, matching

I'm looking for a regular expression that will match if the string contains the character `*`, but **only once**. It should match `a*aa`, `aa*aaaaa`, `a*aaaa`, but it should not match `a**a`, `a****`, `****`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 12):

You can try this pattern:

```
^[^*]*\*[^*]*$
```

Explanations:

```
^      begining of the string
[^*]*  all characters except * zero or more times
\*     literal *
[^*]*  all characters except * zero or more times
$      end of the string
```

Comment: I would prefer `$s =~ /\A [^*]* [*] [^*]* \z/x` ... a little extra whitespace and less punctuation can improve readability. -- *Thanks for the correction*.

Comment: @mickmackusa: The linked question wasn't how to match a character only once in a string (the asker had already a pattern to do that). He only wanted to know how to make this character optional (and in short Allan's answer is: "put a `?`"). That's why it isn't a duplicate of this question. However, it's a very basic question.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear as though you're capturing any of this string -- so why use a regex to begin with? [`tr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) will return the number of matches:

```
my $nStars = ( $str =~ tr/*/*/ );
```

Comment: just `tr/*//`; the replacement list defaults to the search list (unless you say /d)

Comment: @ysth:  I never knew that `if the REPLACEMENTLIST is empty, the SEARCHLIST is replicated. This latter is useful for counting characters...`

Comment: lets you count non-matches, too: `$nonstars = $str =~ tr/*//c`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split function with `/\*/`. If the length of the returned array is 2, it means that you have a single *.