# Regex to match one character exactly one time anywhere inside a string

Tags: regex

I want to match the symbol @ inside a string. It doesn't matter if it is at the beginning, at the middle or at the end of string or anywhere inside it. What matters is to just match it only 0 or 1 times.

I thought of something like this:

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*$
```

But definitely doesn't work because even though it matches the symbol @ once, it can match it only inside the string.

```
@foobar Valid
foo@bar Valid
foobar@ Valid
fooba@r Valid
```

but

```
@@foobar Invalid
@foo@bar Invalid
foo@b@ar Invalid
```

Comment: does my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but are you trying to validate an email address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression to match a character that can only appear once in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869299/regular-expression-to-match-a-character-that-can-only-appear-once-in-a-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*$
```

to forbid to have more than one `@` in your input string.

**Tested:**

https://regex101.com/r/H4hXF5/1

if you need to match also string without the `@` in it add a `?` just after it in the regex:

```
^[^@]*@?[^@]*$
```

this will also match string `abc` for example

**explanations:**

- `^` beginning of line
- `[^@]*` then all char except the `@` taken 0 to N times
- `@` then one `@` char
- `[^@]*` same as step2
- `$` ending of the line
- `?` to have the character before it become optional