# Regex for extractig dots

Tags: regex

I almost lost 4 hours triying to make it work and i give up.

Given the next string:

```
adsdasd.sdfdsfsdf.f43fvev.ASCSDF.sfgsdfssdf.yaml
```

I want a regex, posix possible to:

- substitute all the `.` for `/`
- except the `.yaml` that it should be remain so.

So, this must be the final string:

```
adsdasd/sdfdsfsdf/f43fvev/ASCSDF/sfgsdfssdf.yaml
```

I tried with:

- [Regex to match one character exactly one time anywhere inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365995/regex-to-match-one-character-exactly-one-time-anywhere-inside-a-string)
- [How can I match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124778/how-can-i-match-anything-up-until-this-sequence-of-characters-in-a-regular-exp)
- and regex101

:(

Comment: With `I want a regex, posix` Do you mean you want a POSIX BRE or ERE regex? What is the tool or language that you are using

Comment: terraform, i need it for a replace function

Comment: yes but which regex flavor is it?

Comment: It says it is Perl but....it is not, it is perl but under GO. So almost all lookahead doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

This will help to get all the dots except the last one :

```
\.(?=[^.]*\.)
```

Using a lookahead to check that's there another dot after the one we found (the lookahead's not part of the match).

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LQZkVY/1)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you wanted. https://regex101.com/r/3FpEbq/1

Also in such situation you could replace first all the "." to "/", and then replace "/yaml$" to ".yaml"

Answer (score 1):

You need *negative lookahead* (see https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
\.(?!yaml)
```

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/OdbsUb/1

Answer (score 1):

Generalized expression (means without "yaml" im regex):

positive lookahead like @SelVazi, or negative lookahead below:

```
(?!\.[^.]*$)\.
```

Look at https://regex101.com/r/lcd0ds/1 and https://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to all of you.

But it doesnt work and it wont work.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28846

So i endend doing something like this, which TBH is a piece of crap...but...it opens another question which i will open here because i am again...lost.

```
> regex("/([^/]+)/?$", "fgdfsdf/sfsdfsdfsd/dsfsdfsdfs/gff0fff-fff-ff-dsfssd-cscsd.yaml")
[
  "gff0fff-fff-ff-dsfssd-cscsd.yaml",
```

and wrap it into this horrible oneliner

```
[for k, v in nonsensitive(data.sops_file.account_secrets.data) : "path=${regex("/([^/]+)/?$", replace(replace(k, ".", "/"), "/yaml", ".yaml"))} | data = ${v}"]
```

Yes, this is for importing all secrets from a SOPS file, to vault using several foreach.